# CSS overlapping transparent arrow elements

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is something like this possible with CSS?  I have attempted via before/after pseudo-elements, and while I can get something to work for solid colors, I am having trouble coming up with a way to do it with transparency.

[image: http://puu.sh/ctOL6/875fb5db8f.png]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your code?- codepen.io or jsfiddle.net. Thanks, then we can help you better.

Comment: Please put your code and please elaborate what you had did and what is your problem.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question.  Any previous code attempts are not close to a solution.  This is the closest I had gotten: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmoni

Comment: @user2083984 Does this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/we5ghc62/ ? Do you need the border around the li too?

Comment: @KK this is close to a solution.  I should have clarified though that the background will be an image, not a solid color.  Therefore some kind of transparent border would need to be implemented which seems to be the challenge here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the black borders around each item (as can be seen in the posted image), you still could create the needed shapes by `border` as follows:

```css
.timeline-unit:before, .timeline-unit:after {
    top: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 1.65em;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.timeline-unit:after {
    content: " ";
    left: 100%;
    border-left-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
}

.timeline-unit {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(51,51,51,.8);
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    color: #FFF;
}

.timeline-unit:before { content: none; }

.timeline-unit + .timeline-unit:before {
    content: " ";
    border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    right: 100%;
}

.timeline-unit + .timeline-unit {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

/**************  D E M O  **************/

body {
  background: red;
    
  -webkit-animation: bgcolor 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: bgcolor 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
       -o-animation: bgcolor 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: bgcolor 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgcolor { from { background: red; } to { background: green; }  }
   @-moz-keyframes bgcolor { from { background: red; } to { background: green; }  }
     @-o-keyframes bgcolor { from { background: red; } to { background: green; }  }
        @keyframes bgcolor { from { background: red; } to { background: green; }  }
```

```html
<div class="timeline-unit"> Timeline 1 </div>
<div class="timeline-unit"> Timeline 2 </div>
<div class="timeline-unit"> Timeline 3 </div>
```

However if you need add a border on each item, there are two options:

- Using [`drop-shadow()` filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()) to fake the border - **[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/we5ghc62/2/)** *(supported in Webkit/Firefox35+)*.
- Using [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) in order to create the CSS shapes, so `border` would be unused and available for later usages *(supported in IE9+ as well)*.

Comment: +1 very nice use of em units :)

Comment: Great, clever solution to a complicated problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Very clever and nice demo (with animations) :)

Comment: Excellent solution! I'd just to add one thing: another option to do the stroke like the OP asked is to add an inner element and replicate this logic inside. With a bit o math, paddings and margins (it makes it easier if you use SCSS), it's possible to position the inner element perfectly aligned with the outer element, creating the illusion of a border in each element.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this might work.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 12px 17px 10px 30px;
}
li:first-child {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
li:first-child:before {
  border: 0 none;
}
li:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
  border-top: 20px inset transparent;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
}
li:after {
  content:"";
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #e6e6e6;
  right: -20px;
  border-top: 20px inset transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>daTA1</li>
  <li>daTA2</li>
  <li>daTA3</li>
  <li>daTA4</li>
</ul>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, but this suffers from the transparency issue.  The border separation must be transparent so that the background is still visible.  That's the main problem - I can't use a solid color for the inset border separation.

Comment: @user2083984 If that is what you require, then it is quite hard to achieve. We are relying on the pseudo elements to overlap to "block out" the element, but they can't to that if they are transparent.

Comment: @harley_woop yes I agree.  I'm fairly well-versed in CSS and could not come up with a way to do this (at least that would be manageable to implement).  I don't think using psuedo elements would work at all, but I can't even think of another method of achieving the desired functionality.

Comment: @user2083984 Neither can I. The only thing I could think of would be scaling SVG backgrounds- though I'm not sure that it would work and would be clumsy.